# Why does Windows warn that my password will expire when my account doesn't have one?

Tags: windows-7, passwords, reset

I have a Windows 7 virtual machine set up in Parallels on my Mac. There is only one administrator account set up, with no password, but Windows keeps warning that my password will expire and that I need to change it.

What will happen when it thinks the non-existent password expires? Will it lock me out of my account? Should I just set a password on my account anyway to get around it?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

http://www.computingunleashed.com/turn-off-windows-7-password-protection.html

> In the run menu type control userpasswords. Just press WIN + R to get
>   the RUN menu. The user accounts windows will now open up. Look for the
>   option saying ” Users must enter a user name and password to use this
>   computer ” and uncheck this option and press “OK”.

Comment: I get: `Windows cannot find 'userpasswords2\`. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.`

Comment: try without the 2

Comment: Here's how to do it without using Run: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows7/ht/remove-windows-7-password.htm

Comment: Thanks! But I had to create a password first before I had the option to remove it. So I don't get why Windows was warning me that my password would expire, or what it even thought it was...

Comment: Well as long as you figured it out, that's good.

Comment: @daGUY Type "control userpasswords2" not just "userpasswords2". ;)

Comment: @daGUY - My guess when the account was created you told Windows the password expires.  My personal computer doesn't use a password never got this prompt.

Comment: @techie007 ah, right, `control userpasswords2` did the trick. That checkbox is already unchecked.